# suddenly mail is stop working for linode

Tags: sendmail

Sendmail is stopped sending mail suddenly.

/etc/init.d/sendmail status

```
MSP: is run via cron (20m)
MTA: 5425 /usr/sbin/sendmail-mta -Am -L sm-mta -bd -q10m
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      5425     1  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections
Daemon Status: (process 5652) Console socket child

Current number of children: 0
QueueDir free disk space (in blocks): 43317944
Load average: 0
Child Process 5425 Status: accepting connections

QUE: Same as MTA
```